# ATL/WTL predefined variable _Module : Isn't this illegal identifier in C++?

Tags: c++, atl, identifier, wtl

ATL/WTL automatically creates skeleton codes with global variable _Module defined.
And I've found that WTL expected this to be defined in this specific name till version 7.
I also heard that ATL project wizard also generates symbols such as _Handler, _ServiceMain in user namespace.

Isn't this illegal identifier in C++?
If so, should I rename it (eg. g_Module)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Comment: Identifiers with a leading underscore are reserved to the implementer.  You did not write this code.

Comment: @HansPassant But doesn’t “implementer” here refer to the implementer of the compiler and standard library? ATL/WTL is neither (though I know other frameworks which do the same).

Comment: That is the kind of quibble that forced implementers into the desperation of `__cdecl` and `__attribute__`, etc.  Glad it is not my job.

Comment: @HansPassant Those would also be invalid by the same rules. ;-) But I agree, it’s not a great situation. I have no idea what the best solution would be.